# Why does DataGridViewComboBoxColumn display a ValueMember?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a small problem. `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` displays a value from `ValueMember` and not from `DisplayMember`. The grid works fine and when I select something from this column I see the `DisplayMember` value, but when the focus gets lost, the grid shows a `ValueMember`. I have this code combo box column:

```
statusCBoxColumn.DataSource = dt 'datatable with two fields StatusId and StatusText
statusCBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "StatusText" 'is type NVarchar
statusCBoxColumn.ValueMember = "StatusId" 'is type Int
```

Can anybody help me?

---

Edit: I solved this in the following way:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellFormatting
  If (dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "statusCBoxColumn") Then
    If e.Value & "" > "" Then
      Dim s1 As String = e.Value
      e.Value = GetData("Select StatusText from Status where ID = " & e.Value).ToString()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

But I don't think that it's the best solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set datapropertyName of the comboboxcolumn and added the column to datagridview? You've to write

```
    statusCBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "StatusId";
```

and add the column like

```
    datagridview1.Columns.Add(statusCBoxColumn);
```

Comment: Yes, DataPropertyName is seted and the column is added to datagridview. The datagridview work fine and i can change value of this column but when I change focus from this grid it's show ValueMember not DisplayMember in the ComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The "statusID" for me is long.
I made it by system.type.gettype("System.Int64")
That gave the same behaviour.
When changing it to Int32, the behaviour was OK.

So it was à mismatch between valuemember type and datagridview type.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a 10 years old question, but I was having same problem and I found out that according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.valuemember?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) :

> When the DataSource property is set to a string array, **the ValueMember property does not need to be set** because each string in the array will be used as a valid display string and as a valid underlying value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I've also have a problem on displaying value member,hope it will work.

```
    For index = 0 To cbo.Items.Count - 1
        cbo.SelectedIndex = index 
        MessageBox.Show(CType(cbo.SelectedValue, String))
    Next
```

What i had used is:

```
    Dim jm As Integer
    jm = CType(cmbCategory.SelectedValue, String)
    MsgBox(jm)
```

Answer (score 0):

e.Value = GetData("Select to_char(StatusId) , StatusText from Status where ID = " & e.Value).ToString()

Comment: Hi @skorec1, and welcome to SO! Can you explain this a little bit more? Does it solve the problem? What is the problem? Just more detail is all. Also, please enclose that in a code block ("{}" button) so it's easier to read.